# Create pivot table from variable number of columns

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a data (on left side of picture below), shown the distribution of students in particular week. f.e.: **Student 3** have been on **Station 4** at **Week 40**, etc.

Is it possible to make a report shown on right side by pivot table. The report should picture the *number* of students per each station and week.

I'm totally lost what to put in columns and rows in pivot table setup.

Thx, a lot.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your current data structure is not optimized to use Pivot Tables properly so you'll need to use formulas. I made a fake dataset and used formulas to get your desired output:

[image]

Formula in cell L5 is:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX($B$1:$G$14;;MATCH(L$4;$B$1:$G$1;0));$K5)
```

But if you really wish to use a Pivot Table you need to make your data source a tabular design like this:

[image]

This design will allow to use Pivot Tables properly. Setup is like this:

[image]